# Windows forms Form shaking while rendering child form inside

Tags: c#, winforms

hi i am using windows forms..i had taken  parent form and placed a link in main form and while clicking on the particular link the child form should be accessed but the header and left menu will remains same from main form and the middle block(i.e child form) is changed.I kept form border style to none of the child form.My problem is while clicking on the link the child form...form border style is displayed and it is hidden(like flash it is displayed for a second and dissapear).while clicking on the link the form border style should not disply...

thanks in advance..........

Comment: Reverse-engineering your code from this question is impossible.  Use Form.MdiParent or turn the child form into a user control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called Control.SuspendLayout() and Control.ResumeLayout() ?